# Set a dynamic value as default on a dropdown list on pageload

Tags: javascript, html, salesforce, visualforce

I have a page that loads a value that is different for every user, to get this value I used a visualforce tag as this runs in Salesforce. I only have 2 options, I am giving the user the option to select an option but I already know what the value of the option is for the user opening the page so I want to preselect that value and give them the option to change it.

I am currently doing it like this, the problem is that this creates the same option twice and it doesn't look good but it preselects the correct value, the question is

How can I preselect the correct value without creating the same option twice?

```
 <select id="product" name="liveagent.prechat:Product" style="width:220px" tabindex="5">

                    <option selected="selected">{!$User.Product__c}</option>
                    <option value="Product 1">Product 1</option>
                    <option value="Product 2">Product 2</option>

 </select>
```

//Bear in mind that {!$User.Product__c} can be either Product 1 or Product 2

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be a better way, but you may want to try this:

```
<apex:variable var="SelectedProduct" value="{!IF($User.Product__c=='Product 1','Product 1','Product 2')}" />
<apex:variable var="OtherProduct" value="{!IF($User.Product__c=='Product 2','Product 1','Product 2')}" />

<select id="product" name="liveagent.prechat:Product" style="width:220px" tabindex="5">
    <option value="{!SelectedProduct}" selected="selected" >{!SelectedProduct}</option>
    <option value="{!OtherProduct}" >{!OtherProduct}</option>
</select>
```

Here's a general explanation of the logic:

- If `User.Product__c` is "Product 1" set "Product 1" as the `SelectedProduct`. Because `User.Product__c` is not "Product 2", set "Product 2" as the `OtherProduct`.
- If `User.Product__c` is not "Product 1" set "Product 2" as the `SelectedProduct`. Because `User.Product__c` is "Product 2", set "Product 1" as the `OtherProduct`.

Of course, if you need more than two select options, this method becomes a lot more complicated.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks Matthew. Unfortunately I am getting a "Syntax Error" and that is all the error says, I carefully checked that the syntax was correct, from what I read on the  SFDV dev boards, this is a bug. I appreciate the help but I guess I will have to explore other alternatives. Cheers.

Comment: Instead of using the variables, if that's causing the issue, you can replace the Visualforce `IF` statements with the values.